# SMTP PHPMailer Connection Refused (111)

Tags: php, smtp, smtp-auth

I just deployed a VPS for use it as a SMTP service using [Postal](https://github.com/postalhq/postal)

Apparently it is well settled because I have sent Mails through [smpter.net](https://smpter.net) suscessfully.

My problem is when I try to connect to my SMTP through PHPMailer it always throws me Connection Refused even though I put the same credentials/hostname/port that I have put in SMTPER.net and others websites for SMPT check.

This is my config in my PHPMailer Debug Testing.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                      // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'romailing.me';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->AuthType = 'PLAIN';
```

Plus I have connected suscessfully to Google SMTP for test.

EDIT:

VPS SMTP OS: Ubuntu 16.04

PHPMailer Version: 5.2.26

PHPMailer Debug Info:

```
2020-10-26 20:47:41 Connection: opening to romailing.me:25, timeout=15, options=array ()
2020-10-26 20:47:42 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to romailing.me:25 (Connection refused) [../lib/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 298]
2020-10-26 20:47:42 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
```

Comment: You are not providing enough information for guessing the issue reason. What OS is VPS? Did you configure DNS server properly e.g. can you ping your domain `romailing.me` from inside VPS? What version of PHPMailer? Did yout turn on debug mode in PHPMailer via `setDebugLevel(SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION)` ? If yes, what's output? Generally PHPMailer works well, it's solid & stable app. I'd guess issue is with environment configuration on VPS.

Comment: Hello.
I have edited the information.

Regarding to DNS configuration it should be properly. I tested the ping from my domain from inside my VPS:

`PING romailing.me (207.246.70.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 207.246.70.139.vultr.com (207.246.70.139): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=              0.034 ms`

If you check romailing.me with Port 25 in a smtp tester connection isn't refused.

https://www.wormly.com/test-smtp-server/host/romailing.me/port/25/sendmail/0/id/I6HQ0aeT

Comment: You are using pretty old PHPMailer version 5.2.26, currenlty 6.1.8. There have been some important changes & improvements under the hood. You may try `telnet 207.246.70.139 25` - see whether port 25 is allowed at target server. Also I see `$mail->AuthType = 'PLAIN';` which means you need to supply base64 encoded credentials - see https://bobcares.com/blog/phpmailer-authtype/ . If target server redirects to secure connection you may want to disable temporarily SSL peer verification in case cert is not valid - see https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544 .